# Gulp tasks won't terminate

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I am unable to terminate my tasks using `gulp.watch`, or plugins like BrowserSync when I press `CRTL-C`. As an example, this is the content of my gulpfile:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('server', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['server']);
```

In this screenshot I show what happens when I try to terminate the task:

[image]

You can observe several unsuccessful attempts to terminate by pressing `CRTL-C`.

As I wrote earlier, this problem is not exclusive of BrowserSync, it also happens when I run `gulp.watch`. I suppose this affects all similar plugins.

Comment: I'm not sure if this hits your problem, but if you don't terminate the streams, they might live on in your system, preventing you from killing it. Try calling the done callback: https://gist.github.com/ddprrt/24df78dd81ca7303e43c